# Отправка сообщений от имени бота discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
import asyncio

client = discord.Client()

async def greatSender(): 
    channel = discord.Object(id=input('channel id'))
    await client.send_message(channel, input('message'))

async def on_ready():
    print( 'Bot ready' )
    greatSender()
token = open('token.txt' , 'r').readline()

client.run(token)
```

Я хотел сделать отправку сообщений от имени бота, но всё полностью зависает ошибок нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот решение проблемы (сначала вводится ID текстового канала, затем отсылается сообщение после ввода сообщения в консоль):

```py
async def greatSender():
    channel = client.get_channel(id=int(input('channelID: ')))
    await channel.send(input('message: '))

@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print( 'Bot ready' )
    await greatSender()
```